# JavaScript only running when class file contains parenthesis in name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm new to JavaScript and wanted to code a game I had previously coded in Java. I was coding with the p5.js library, and using the Atom text editor. The game I was making was Asteroids and it was working fine. I had figured out how to add the ship and the lasers. Then I added the code for the actual asteroids. (I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but as I said before, I was copying the code from a Java project and when I went to add the asteroids I basically copied the whole thing over, without saving it until I was done.) After I added them, I tried to run it, and I said "asteroid is not defined", because I forgot to add a reference to it in the HTML. However, after I ran it again, the page stopped loading and eventually crashed (I got the "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong when displaying this webpage" error). I thought it was the HTML at first, but when I added the class to the main script, it still crashed. After an hour, I realized that if I added parenthesis to the class name (class ship(){}) then the page would load. However, I would get a syntax error as expected. The same thing would happen if I declared the object as the class like you would do in Java (Ship ship;), it would run but it would say "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". I'm not sure how to get around this, or why not adding parenthesis to a class name would cause the program not to run.

Attached are the first part of my main script, the constructor of my ship class, and my asteroid class because the problems only started after adding it.

Any help or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Main Script:

```
let ship;
let bullets = [];
let asteroids = [];
//             Left   Right  Boost  Slow   Shoot
let keyDown = [false, false, false, false, false];
function setup(){
  window.canvas = createCanvas(800, 600);
  ship = new Ship(width/2, height/2);
  for(let i = 0; i = 4; i++){
    asteroids.push(new asteroid(random(width), random(height), 100));
  }
  frameRate(60);

}

function draw(){
  background(0);
  checkKeys();
  ship.update();
  ship.show();

  for(let i = bullets.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    bullets[i].update();
    bullets[i].show();

    if(!bullets[i].alive){
      bullets.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for(let i = asteroids.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    asteroids[i].update();
    asteroids[i].show();
  }

}
```

Ship Class:

```
class Ship{
  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.midX = this.x + 15;
    this.midY = this.y + 20;
    this.heading = 0;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.boosting = false;
  }
```

Asteroid Class:

```
class asteroid{
  constructor(x, y, size){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.velX = random(-2, 3);
    this.velY = random(-2, 3);

    if(this.velX == 0){
      this.velX++;
    }

    if(this.velY == 0){
      this.velY++;
    }

    this.points = random(4, 12);
    this.xPoints = [];
    this.yPoints = [];
    this.offsets = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.points; i++){
      this.offsets[i] = random(-size/5, (size/5)+1);
    }
  }

  update(){
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.y += this.velY;
  }

  show(){
    stroke(255);

    beginShape();
    for(let i; i < this.points; i++){
      let angle = i*(360/this.points);
      let px = (this.size/2 + this.offsets[i]) * cos(angle);
      let py = (this.size/2 + this.offsets[i]) * sin(angle);
      this.xPoints[i] = px + this.x;
      this.yPoints[i] = py + this.y;
      vertex(px, py);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the code, I got the same error.  Turns out your `ship` class has no closing bracket `}` for the class, only for the constructor.  Adding that and now I get no errors

```js
let ship;
let bullets = [];
let asteroids = [];
//             Left   Right  Boost  Slow   Shoot
let keyDown = [false, false, false, false, false];
function setup(){
  window.canvas = createCanvas(800, 600);
  ship = new Ship(width/2, height/2);
  for(let i = 0; i = 4; i++){
    asteroids.push(new asteroid(random(width), random(height), 100));
  }
  frameRate(60);

}

function draw(){
  background(0);
  checkKeys();
  ship.update();
  ship.show();

  for(let i = bullets.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    bullets[i].update();
    bullets[i].show();

    if(!bullets[i].alive){
      bullets.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for(let i = asteroids.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    asteroids[i].update();
    asteroids[i].show();
  }

}


class Ship{
  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.midX = this.x + 15;
    this.midY = this.y + 20;
    this.heading = 0;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.boosting = false;
  }
}  //<--- I added this bracket


class asteroid{
  constructor(x, y, size){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.velX = random(-2, 3);
    this.velY = random(-2, 3);

    if(this.velX == 0){
      this.velX++;
    }

    if(this.velY == 0){
      this.velY++;
    }

    this.points = random(4, 12);
    this.xPoints = [];
    this.yPoints = [];
    this.offsets = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.points; i++){
      this.offsets[i] = random(-size/5, (size/5)+1);
    }
  }

  update(){
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.y += this.velY;
  }

  show(){
    stroke(255);

    beginShape();
    for(let i; i < this.points; i++){
      let angle = i*(360/this.points);
      let px = (this.size/2 + this.offsets[i]) * cos(angle);
      let py = (this.size/2 + this.offsets[i]) * sin(angle);
      this.xPoints[i] = px + this.x;
      this.yPoints[i] = py + this.y;
      vertex(px, py);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I don't think that's the problem. Like I said I only posted part of the class. In my actual code, the brackets are fine.

Comment: I can post the entire class file if need be

Comment: Also something weird, when I deleted the last bracket of the class, the page actually ran, but I got a syntax error, so I still couldn't do anything.

Comment: This still sounds like a similar issue... I would try running your code though a linter/validator to see if it can find the issue.  It's most likely a syntax issue of some kind.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. I found a linter online, and it turns out I had some syntax problems. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cool!  I strongly suggest finding a linter plugin for your IDE in that case.  My go-to is TSLint for VSCode, but there's also ESLint and JSLint.  Having that in your IDE will help point out issues as you type them.